# Are any canyons in the Sierra de Grazalema accessible without special canyoneering gear?

Tags: hiking, canyoning, spain

The book [Sierra de Grazalema: Complete Guidebook to the Natural Park](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sierra-Grazalema-Complete-Guidebook-Natural/dp/8493565385) includes a chapter on canyons, describing two routes: one Garganta Verde and one through the Garganta de las Buitreras.  Both require rope, karabiner, helmet, harness, etc.  Are there any canyons in or near the Natural Park where one can access using only normal hiking gear?